# Ruby on Rails: short hand to put commas in between elements in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
users_allowed_to_be_viewed.map {|u| "#{u.id},"}
```

but that gives `1,2,3,`

What would be a short way to just get something like `1,2,3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

an array?

from http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html

```
 array.join(sep=$,) → str

Returns a string created by converting each element of the array to a string, separated by sep.

       [ "a", "b", "c" ].join        #=> "abc"
       [ "a", "b", "c" ].join("-")   #=> "a-b-c"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
users_allowed_to_be_viewed.map{|u| u.id}.join(",")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
users_allowed_to_be_viewed.map(&:id).join(',')
```

`Array#join` is also aliased to `Array#*`, although that might make things a little obtuse:

```
users_allowed_to_be_viewed.map(&:id) * ','
```

Answer (score 2):

```
users_allowed_to_be_viewed.join ',' 

ruby-1.8.7-p299 > users_allowed_to_be_viewed = [1,2,3]
   => [1, 2, 3] 
ruby-1.8.7-p299 > users_allowed_to_be_viewed.join ',' 
    => "1,2,3"
```

Comment: bah missed the u.id, part.. /sigh.. (see other answers to use the map + join to get what you actually wanted... )